# global varible address truncated when compile with clang memory sanitizer

Tags: memory, clang, sanitizer

I'm trying to build my code with clang memory sanitizer.
I get following error when execuatable starts:

> thread #1, name = 'esp_exec-N', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0x555643df5c8)
> frame #0: 0x000055555b7806ae esp_exec-N`calloc(n=1, size=32) at mem_turbo.c:592:8
> 589    size_t bytes = n * size;
> 590    void *obj;
> 591 
> ->592    if (!mem_initialized) {
> 593      mem_initialize();
> 594    }
> 595

Then I read the address of mem_initialized

> (lldb) ta v &mem_initialized
> (int *) &mem_initialized = 0x00005555643df5c8

The first 20 bits of the pionter value was truncated(one less 5)

after disassamble, I can find following sections in object file, the value of the pointer was truncated here.

> 0x55555b7806a1 <+81>:  movabsq $0x500000000000, %r13     ; imm = 0x500000000000 
> 0x55555b7806ab <+91>:  xorq   %r13, %rcx
> ->0x55555b7806ae <+94>:  movl   (%rcx), %ecx

clang version: 9.0.1
full compile command of this object:
clang  -I. -I../include -I../../include -I../../../snps/include -I/slowfs/swe101/yinliu/esp_main_msan_test/tcl/headers -I/slowfs/swe101/yinliu/esp_main_msan_test/tcl/tcl8.6/include -fPIC -g -fPIE  -fsanitize=memory -fsanitize-memory-track-origins -pie -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -g -m64 -DMEM_USE_MMAP   -o /slowfs/swe101/yinliu/esp_main_msan_test/objroot/common/memory/mem/obj-linux64/mem_turbo-N.o -DINNO_OPT -DNDEBUG  -c  -DSynopsys_Optimize -DSynopsys_amd64   -DSynopsys_linux64 -DSynopsys_linux -msse2 -mfpmath=sse  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-dollars-in-identifiers -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wnested-externs -Wmissing-prototypes  -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-unused-local-typedefs -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-writable-strings -Wno-unused-private-field -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-undefined-var-template -Wno-trigraphs -Wno-unused-local-typedef -Wno-mismatched-tags -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fnew-alignment=8 -Wno-error -Wno-implicit-fallthrough -Wno-deprecated-register -Wno-varargs -Wno-return-type -Wno-self-assign -Wno-c++17-extensions   mem_turbo.c

If I remove the memory sanitizer related build options, the pointer trunction was gone.
But I need them in this case.